Which Arduino CMake Toolchain should be used?
I am working on an Arduino UNO board and I want to build my Arduino sketch with CMake.
It looks to me there is no official Arduino toolchain version to go by, and I found at least three available toolchains that can be used:

https://github.com/a9183756-gh/Arduino-CMake-Toolchain (last updated 4 years ago)
https://github.com/technyon/Arduino-CMake-Toolchain (a fork of the preceding one)
https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake (last updated a long time ago, but referenced in this tutorial)

Which one should be used?

I've had good luck with this one, which has been updated recently and provides a solid CMake setup for building Arduino programs. Specifically, it includes toolchains for the Arduino UNO, as well as a couple of other Arduino boards.
It also includes some screenshots with instructions for how to utilize it with VSCode's CMake extension, if that is of interest to you.
